# Playing Python audio in Ubuntu

Tags: python

I'm trying to play a sample .mp3 audio file. The code (works perfectly on Windows PyCharm) is:

```
import vlc
from contextlib import redirect_stdout
from io import StringIO
import time


url = '//samplelib.com/lib/preview/mp3/sample-3s.mp3'
p = vlc.MediaPlayer("https:{}".format(url))
with redirect_stdout(StringIO()):
    p.play()
time.sleep(5)
```

However when I try to run the same code in Ubuntu, it's showing me the below errors. I have installed vlc with `pip3 install python-vlc`.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pydic.py", line 8, in <module>
    p = vlc.MediaPlayer("https:{}".format(url))
  File "/home/avi-ubu/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/vlc.py", line 3252, in __new__
    instance = get_default_instance()
  File "/home/avi-ubu/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/vlc.py", line 261, in get_default_instance
    _default_instance = Instance()
  File "/home/avi-ubu/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/vlc.py", line 1803, in __new__
    return libvlc_new(len(args), args)
  File "/home/avi-ubu/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/vlc.py", line 4969, in libvlc_new
    _Cfunction('libvlc_new', ((1,), (1,),), class_result(Instance),
  File "/home/avi-ubu/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/vlc.py", line 292, in _Cfunction
    raise NameError('no function %r' % (name,))
NameError: no function 'libvlc_new'
```

I tried other alternatives like `playsound`, `pygame`, etc, but they didn't seem to work on either my Windows or Ubuntu.

Comment: I've never used this library, but that question looks promising. I found it by googling `python vlc NameError: no function 'libvlc_new'`. In the future, please try your own research first.

Comment: sudo apt-get install vlc did the magic. I had done pip3 install python-vlc earlier so I thought vlc was already installed.